# Intellij, any file is too large and can't be opened on samsung ARM Chromebook

Tags: intellij-idea, arm, chromebook

I followed this [tutorial](http://fuzzyquery.wordpress.com/2013/09/15/developing-on-a-samsung-chromebook-arm/) to install Intellij on my Samsung ARM Chromebook. The installation was fine, but whenever I open a file which is more than 1 byte, it says that the file is too large for Intellij IDEA editor.

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug and you should report it to [JetBrains](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).